# Can someone help me with this code, it's not returning the results I want to

Tags: java

Can anyone compile this code and help me because it's not returning the results I want. I don't know if the return is not working or what, please help me, here is the code:

```
public class ComputeAverage {
public static void main (String[] args) {

new ComputeAverage().computeAverage(4);
}

 
 public double computeAverage(int how_many)
{ double total_points = 0.0;  // the total of all test scores
  int count = 0;  // the quantity of tests read so far
  while ( count != how_many )
        // at each iteration: total_points == exam_1 + exam_2 + ... + exam_count
        { // ask the user for the next exam score:
          String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type next exam score:");
          int score = new Integer(input).intValue();
          if (score < 0) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter a positive numer");
         total_points = total_points - score;
          }
           
          // add it to the total:
          total_points = total_points + score;
          count = count + 1;
          // print a summary of the progress:
          System.out.println("count = " + count + "; total = " + total_points);
         
        }

        // at conclusion: total_points == exam_1 + exam_2 + ... + exam_how_many
   return (total_points / how_many);
 
}
 

 }
```

Comment: You should explain what the code is doing (what result) and then what you want it to do instead (what result you want to see).  "The result I want" isn't really something we can guess at.

Comment: @dreamcrash can you show me the code

Comment: @1Skillz never mind that, what do you real expect to happen?

Comment: Its pretty obvious, enter n numbers, return the average. It looks like the problem is in the UI part rather than in computing the average. For that there's more info/code needed.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) Use [edit] option to clarify your question.

Comment: you have just call the `computeAverage(4)` method and don't collect the return value and there is no code to display it. the return value and show it in the same way as collection input from user.  `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Final Score : " +new ComputeAverage().computeAverage(4))`

Answer (score 1):

You are returning the value back to the main but you are not printing it anywhere. you can use the alert box in swings to show the result.

In main function instead of .,

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
   new ComputeAverage().computeAverage(4);
}
```

try :

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Exam score : " + new ComputeAverage().computeAverage(4));
}
```